# How can I remove this address duplicate with regex (PHP)?

Tags: php, regex

I've some texts like this below, what I want is to delete the last address match, the problem is that these addresses have different formats, depend of the text:

I have this:

`To find out more about Groupon Goods, see the <a  href="http://www.groupon.co.uk/faq"> FAQ</a>.\n\nUK-Bedding Returns:Albany Mill, Old Hall Street, Middleton, Manchester M241AG
UK-Bedding Returns:Albany Mill, Old Hall Street, Middleton
Manchester M241AG\n\n<a href="http://www.groupon.co.uk/terms_and_conditions"></a>
Built by gskinner.com with Fl`

Output should be this (I've removed the last "Albany Mill, Old Hall Street, Middleton
Manchester M241AG"):

`To find out more about Groupon Goods, see the <a  href="http://www.groupon.co.uk/faq"> FAQ</a>.\n\nUK-Bedding Returns:Albany Mill, Old Hall Street, Middleton, Manchester M241AG
UK-Bedding Returns:\n\n<a href="http://www.groupon.co.uk/terms_and_conditions"></a>
Built by gskinner.com with Fl`

Comment: Question is not clear, please edit the question showing the expected output.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I'm trying different options with match_all, and preg_replace, but.....really the problem is not about the pattern I think, is about the process, how can I detect this duplicate and select later the last match?

Comment: Is there always going to be a duplicate?

Comment: yes, there is a duplicate

Comment: +1 for give courage to newcomer. Do not down vote immidiately, guide the user to impruve himsel/herself.

Answer (score 1):

If there always is a duplicate, I would go a different way:

- Split the text by new-lines (using preg_split as there are multiple new-lines);
- Locate the line with the address;
- Cut it in half.

So, in your example, something like (extra verbose):

```
$lines = preg_split('#\n+#', $text);
$addresses = $lines[1];
$address = substr($addresses, 0, floor(strlen($addresses) / 2));
```